# TSQL: How does this JOIN resolve?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing these joins:

```
from #lps_at_lines2 as l2
left join jobmatl as jm on l2.item = jm.item
inner join job as j on jm.job = j.job
    and jm.suffix = j.suffix
```

I'm not sure how the join would resolve and [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(SQL.90).aspx) is like reading hieroglyphics to me.

My guess is that first `#lps_at_lines2` gets `LEFT JOIN`'d to `jobmatl` and then somehow `job` gets `INNER JOIN`'d to jm afterwards. Is that correct?

Comment: change your inner join to be a left outer join

Comment: @ganders why? My question is about how this join would resolve.

Comment: When an l2 record has no match in jm, then a pseudo jm record gets joined with all its columns null. Then j gets inner joined to jm, but as the nulls can not match (e.g. jm.job = j.job cannot match when jm.job is null) all outer joined jm get discarded again. So you are where you would have been with `inner join jobmatl as jm`. If you want this so, change this join; if you want outer joins instead, change `inner join job as j` to `left join job as j`.

Comment: left to right, what else?

Comment: By 'resolve' do you mean how does it get parsed, or how does it actually execute?  Parse order is left to right, but actual execution could (generally) be any order, whatever the optimizer feels is best.

Answer (score 5):

In a `FROM` clause, `JOIN`s are parsed left to right -- the reading order in English.  So, the `LEFT JOIN` is processed (logically) before the `INNER JOIN`.

The `INNER JOIN` conditions include:

```
jm.job = j.job and jm.suffix = j.suffix
```

These refer to the second table of the `LEFT JOIN`.  Because `NULL` values fail, the `INNER JOIN` is turning the preceding `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  In other words, you should get the same results using `INNER JOIN` for both.

Note that you can adjust the prioritization by using parentheses, but your version of the query does not do this.

In general, when mixing inner joins and left joins, I start by including all the inner joins and then `LEFT JOIN`ing the additional tables.